# GRUB problem while Installing Ubuntu 16.04.5 lts

Tags: grub2

while clean installing Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS I'm having the GRUB installation problem that is causing my installer to crash. The link below

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JgRsXJ5WsP/

Any help?

Comment: Shut Windows down fully, not hibernated.  Then grub may install.

Comment: While you have a new UEFI system, somehow you have Windows in the now 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. You must then boot Ubuntu installer in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode to install grub in BIOS boot mode. But if Windows needs repairs, you have to directly boot Windows which means reinstall of BIOS Windows boot loader. So make Windows repair disk first. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI mode since 2012.